# Target plugins in Java Search in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to know that how we can include all the Target Plug-ins in Java search at once. I know how to include a single target plug in in Java search but I don't know how to include all the target plug-ins at once in Java search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that this option is checked - 'Preferences > Plug-in development > Include all plug-ins from target in Java Search'

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the third item in http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part4.html#TargetPlatform

> You can automatically synchronize Java search operations with the target platform via the Preferences > Plug-in Development preference page.

[image]

> Java search operations are scoped to workspace projects and their dependencies. Developers don't typically have the entire target platform in their workspace and thus Java search operations don't locate references from many upstream plug-ins. You can manually add plug-ins to the Java search path using the Add All Plug-ins to Java Search action in the Plug-ins view. However, the new preference automatically keeps the search path in synch with the target platform.
>
> Under the covers a project named External Plug-in Libraries is created with all external plug-ins in the target platform on its build path.